# how to prove $\cot^2x = \cos^2x+(\cot x \cos x)^2?$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to prove this equation, but I am completely stuck as to how I can go about using the trigonometric identities for the proof.

> $$\cot^2x = \cos^2x+(\cot x \cos x)^2?$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $1+\cot^2x=\dfrac1{\sin^2x}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\cos^2(x)[1+\cot^2(x)] = \cos^2(x)\csc^2(x) = \cot^2(x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The right-hand side is given by $$\cos^2(x)+\frac{\cos^4(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=\cos^2(x)\left(1+\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\right)=\cos^2(x)\left(\frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\right)=…$$

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the RHS to simplify to the LHS:

$\cos^2(x) + (\cot(x)\cos(x))^2$

= $\cos^2(x) + (\cot^2(x)\cos^2(x))$

= $\cos^2(x) + \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\tan^2(x)}$

= $\cos^2(x) (1+ \frac{1}{\tan^2(x)})$

= $\cos^2(x) \frac{\tan^2(x) + 1}{\tan^2(x)}$

Using the pythagorean identity that $1 + \tan^2(x) = \sec^2(x)$ we see that:

= $\cos^2(x) \frac{\sec^2(x)}{\tan^2(x)}$

Using the fact that, by definition, sec(x) and tan(x) are inverses of cos(x) and cot(x) respectively, we find that:

= $\cos^2(x) \frac{\cot^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$

= $\cot^2(x)$

Answer (score 0):

The left-hand side can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{align}
\cot^2(x)&=\frac{1}{\tan^2(x)}\\
&=\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}.
\end{align}
$$

Now we focus on the right-hand side. We rewrite the $\cot^2(x)$ in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$:
$$
\begin{align}
\cos^2(x)+\cot^2(x)\cos^2(x)&=\cos^2(x)\left(1+\cot^2(x)\right),\\
&=\cos^2(x)\left(1+\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\right),\\
&=\cos^2(x)\left(\frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\right),\\
&=\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)},
\end{align}
$$
and thus we are done since the left-hand side is equal to the right-hand side.